# What are important design parameters for Opto-isolators?

Tags: opto-isolator

I want to use an opto-isolator in my circuit. I found Opto-isolator 6N135 matching with my design voltage requirement. datasheet (http://www.vishay.com/docs/83604/6n135.pdf). But datasheet seems to be confusing. I want to know basic and important design parameters for a opto-isolator (with reference to data sheet). Can someone help me for the same ?

Comment: what specifically is the circuit you want to use it in. A general answer is not really easy to simply give.

Answer (score 2):

The single most important parameter that's peculiar to Opto-isolators is CTR (Current Transfer Ratio). It's kind of like \$\beta\$ for a BJT, in that it defines how much current shows up on the output (photo-diode or photo-transistor) side given an amount of current driven into the LED side. CTR is a function of temperature (positive temp coef) and age. CTR falls off by about 30% as the part ages.

The 6n135 is a fast(ish) part where the optical transfer is from LED to photo-diode. That means that for the part to work the cathode of the photo-diode (Vcc) has to be connected to a bias voltage, typically 5V. Photo-diode current gets buffered through a BJT output transistor, which adds some current gain to the CTR number. If you look at Figure 4 (page 4) of the data sheet you will see how LED current converts to output collector current.

For more about this you could look at [App Note 02](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83741/83741.pdf). The first 2 pages talk about CTR. Also good is [App Note 45](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83706/83706.pdf).

Comment: Those app notes are good starters, especially if you target digital application of optocouplers. If someone is interested in analog/linear ones... that's actually more hairy to pull off properly with optocouplers... Avago (nee HP) has a good intro on the topic in their [Application Note 951-2](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/5954-8430E).